# Kafka Java Producer with Kerberos authentication

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934578/kafka-java-producer-with-kerberos/36334085) question before posting the question. It was using 0.8.0 version of Kafka producer code.

We are using `Kafka 0.9.0.1 version`. Since our cluster is secured one using `Kerberos authentication`. How can i set the Kerberos authentication details programatically?

When i try to send the message , the message is not reaching to Kafka topic. I confirmed this using getting the result of Async `send` operation from the Producer `Future<RecordMetadata>` and it was throwing the timeout exception.

**Sample Code:**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "1.2.3.4:6667");
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 2);
//      props.put("security.inter.broker.protocol","PLAINTEXTSASL");
        props.put("security.protocol", "PLAINTEXTSASL");//WHEN I TRY THIS ITS THROWING ERROR
        props.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name","zookeeper");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        try {
            Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("kafkaTest", "kafka test message"));
            // Thread.sleep(4000);
            // producer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Do i have to change anything on the `jaas` file? I dont see any documentation for Java API with Kerberos authentication.

**The timeout exception is:**

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$FutureFailure.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:686)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:449)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:339)
    at com.scb.upv.SimpleKafkaProducer.main(SimpleKafkaProducer.java:26)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Comment: Did you follow the [instructions in the Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#security) for setting up the kerberos authentication?

Comment: Have you solved this?