# Unable to configure KafkaChannel or KafkaSource in Flume for Kerberos enabled cluster-LoginException

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, cloudera, flume, flume-ng

I try to setup KafkaChannel (or KafkaSource) in Flume. And I constantly receive following Exception

> Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login:
>       the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code 
>       does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. 
>       Make sure -Djava.security.auth.login.config property passed to JVM 
>       and the client is configured to use a ticket cache 
>       (using the JAAS configuration setting 'useTicketCache=true)'. 
>       Make sure you are using FQDN of the Kafka broker you are trying to 
>       connect to. not available to garner  authentication information from the user

My `jaas.conf` is following:

```
KafkaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
storeKey=true
serviceName="kafka"
keyTab="flume-kafka.keytab"
principal="flume/kafka@MYDOMAIN.COM";
};
```

I have provided this confgration to Flume via

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/jaas.conf "
```

And finally I have specified

```
agent.channels.myChannel.kafka.consumer.security.protocol = SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

Does anyone have any ideas why Flume does not use keyTab? Let me know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934578/kafka-java-producer-with-kerberos) ([original](http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/02/21/secure-kafka-java-producer-with-kerberos/)) I've noticed that `KafkaClient` config specified in [Flume 1.6 documentation provided by Cloudera](http://archive-primary.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/flume-ng-1.6.0-cdh5.10.1/FlumeUserGuide.html#kafka-channel) was missing some options. Then I took a look at [Official Apache Flume 1.7 documentation](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#kafka-channel) and noticed that I miss the following properties:

```
a1.channels.channel1.kafka.consumer.sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
a1.channels.channel1.kafka.consumer.sasl.kerberos.service.name = kafka
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the kafka document, the sasl_plaintext has been addedd in version `0.10`.

> SASL/GSSAPI (Kerberos) - starting at version 0.9.0.0
>
> SASL/PLAIN - starting at version 0.10.0.0
>
> SASL/SCRAM-SHA-256 and SASL/SCRAM-SHA-512 - starting at version 0.10.2.0

But the flume version `1.8` still use `kafka_client_2.11_0.9.1.jar`. I think it may be the bug of flume.
You can rewrite the flume-kafka-sink.jar to fix the bug.

[Kafka Document](http://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation.html)

[Flume Kafka sink](https://github.com/apache/flume/tree/trunk/flume-ng-sinks/flume-ng-kafka-sink)

Answer (score 0):

KafkaClient 
config pasted can be sued.

The above is fine but the things to be cautious about is the following 
1. the principal name for a non Cloudera user must be exactly as it shows in a KLIST.
2. very basic, use a full path to the key tab file

Next JAVA_OPTS is a must from the command line if using "Kafka-console-consumer" or in the config parameters if using Cloudera manager.

if using the Kafka-console-consumer, remember to use the --consumer.config switch point to the client.properties file.

After all the above are done, you may still receive the same error.
That is due to ACL.
user the Kafka documentation and set the permission for the Kafka topics for the user used above (including Kafka) to allow the access. Unless you do that, you do not have any access to the topics and will show the same error.

best wishes.